# Work with DDE Links from Excel to Shiny in R

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have a DDE link that feeds my excel spreadsheet. This is the DDE Link: `NAMEofTheCOMPANY|cot!STOCKA.LAST`, which hands me the real-time market stock price. I then paste it to a cell on the excel spreadsheet which works fine.

What I need is the following:

1. With this DDE link in my Excel spreadsheet, how do I "send it" to Shiny?
2. How do you work with DDE links? Is there a way I can "send" this link DIRECT to Shiny without having to go through my Excel spreadsheet and then send it to Shiny?

Comment: You could have a look at: https://rdrr.io/cran/tcltk2/man/windows/tk2dde.html. If you want / have to stay with excel you can listen on changes of the "modified at" time stamp of your excel file (does it change?) from shiny . For the latter we could provide code (in case its a valid  approach).

Comment: @BigDataScientist its really hard. I dont know if Im doing it right. Can you hep me? My excel file is `ddelink.xlsm`. The dde link comes in this format: `NAMEofTheCOMPANY|cot!STOCKA.LAST`. So I did this on R: `tk2dde.request("Excel", "{[ddeLink.xlsm]Planilha1}", "B2:B10") `  I got this message: `"Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = \"tclObj\") : \n  [tcl] dde command failed.\n\n"`

Comment: Hmm i cant see an obvious error. However, i have never worked with that package and dont have access to your DDE link, so its hardly possible help with that approach. I could help with the "modified file change" listener,...